# Set React-class-state on prop change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, state, react-props

So I´m having this issue with my react class component.
Since it´s handling "a lot" of state, I don´t want to use a functional component bc I think it is more readable like so.
A few layers down from my class component I have a features component, which dispatches selected features from checkboxes to the redux state.

My class component needs to know these changes and re-renders based on the selected features, stored in the redux store.

The problem is, it always gets the new props from the mapStaeToProps function, but I can´t setState(...) based on the new props, bc componentDidMount only runs once at the beginning or componentWillReceiveProps() doesn´t exist anymore.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import TaggingComponent from '../../../content-components/TaggingComponent';
import SupplyAmount from '../../../content-components/SupplyAmount';
import FeaturesComponent from '../../../content-components/FeaturesComponent';
import './TokenGenerator.css';

const features = {
  Features: [
    'Mintable',
    'Burnable',
    'Pausable',
    'Permit',
    'Votes',
    'Flash Minting',
    'Snapchots'
  ],
  'Access Control': ['Ownable', 'Roles'],
  Upgradeability: ['Transparent', 'UUPS']
};

class TokenGenerator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tokenName: '',
      shortName: '',
      supplyAmount: null,
      selectedFeatures: this.props.selectedFeatures
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, current_state) {
    if (current_state.selectedFeatures !== props.selectedFeatures) {
      return {
        selectedFeatures: props.selectedFeatures
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  setTokenName = (e) => {
    this.setState({ tokenName: e.target.value });
  };

  setShortageName = (e) => {
    this.setState({ shortName: e.target.value });
  };

  setAmount = (e) => {
    this.setState({ supplyAmount: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="grid grid-cols-7 gap-10">
        {/* Name and shortage input */}
        <TaggingComponent
          setTokenName={this.setTokenName}
          setShortageName={this.setShortageName}
        />
        {/* Token supply */}
        <SupplyAmount setAmount={this.setAmount} />
        {/* Tokenfeatures */}

        <FeaturesComponent features={features} />

        {/* Selected Features listing */}
        <div className="card-bg border-2 border-white text-white p-11 rounded col-span-5 row-span-5">
          <h4 className="text-center">Selected Features</h4>
          {this.state.selectedFeatures.map((feature) => {
            return <p key={feature}>{feature}</p>;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state);
  return { selectedFeatures: state.tokenGeneratorState.selectedFeatures };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TokenGenerator);
```

Is the new getDerivedStateFromProps method the only way to update state vom changing props?

Cheers

Comment: The solution is going to depend what you're doing when the props change. Setting state as a result of props changing is needed for some niche circumstances, but is not a common thing to do. You might find this article useful: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: If a component is receiving props, then why do you need to re-set the state locally?  The child should re-render when the prop changes.  I would suggest letting us see some code so we can help.

Comment: Edited the question with my class component.

Edit´s edit: Oh dam I just realized I can simply render the features straighz from the props instead of first setting the state and THAN render based on class state... Wow I´m lost Ig... Thanks, you actually really helped me out by rethinking the nonsense I came up with!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set state for each prop change. Because the component which receives props will re-render automatically whenever any of it's props changes.

Take this as example,

```
class ComponentA {
    render() {
        <ComponentB someProp={someDynamicallyChangingValue} />
    }
}

class ComponentB {
    render() {
        <div>{this.props.someProp}</div>
    }
}
```

Here, the ComponentB will be automatically re-rendered whenever **someProp** is changed in ComponentA.